# How to get rank position from @curRank

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rank

want to call up a ranking position is it posible with @curRank?

I created a rank table with

```
    SELECT `item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) AS `rank`, @curRank := @curRank 
+ 1 AS `ranking`  FROM `rtgitems`, (SELECT 

    @curRank := 0) r WHERE item
    REGEXP 'Total'
     ORDER BY (`totalrate` / `nrrates`)  DESC
```

I get a table

```
item       rank      ranking 

Karla       9.5       1
Kelly       9.3       2
Arian       9.1429    3
```

in the kelly page i want to call up her ranking position

```
    SELECT `item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) 
AS `rank`, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS `ranking` 
FROM `rtgitems`, 
(SELECT @curRank := 0) r WHERE item REGEXP 'kelly' 
ORDER BY (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) DESC LIMIT 10
echo "<td align='center' width='250'>" . $row['ranking'] . "</td>";
```

but it only gives me a 1 instead of 2

Comment: show us how you form $row[ranking] and what is kelly page

Comment: I call the kelly ranking by REGEXP 'kelly'

Comment: The problem is the rank is calculated on the fly,so when you add REGEXP kelly it searches only for one person so the rank is one.Create a column and update it with rank and run a trigger to recalculate teh rank each day.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `WHERE` clause out of ranking calculation results.

**Example**:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        `item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) AS `rank`, 
        @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS `ranking` 
    FROM `rtgitems`, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
    ORDER BY (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) DESC 
    LIMIT 10
) results
WHERE item REGEXP 'kelly'
```

Comment: Yep same thing as an alias

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the solutions:

1. You need to use a subquery to maintain rank position.

This will give you a result whose rank is 4:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT item, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) AS `rank`,     
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS ranking
    FROM rtgitems p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
    ORDER BY (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) DESC
) AS stat
WHERE ranking = 2;
```

2. You can even use `LIMIT OFFSET` to query as they are already in order:

```
    SELECT item, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) AS `rank`
    FROM rtgitems
    ORDER BY (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) DESC 
    LIMIT 4, 1
```