# How to get rank position from MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the rank value of a MySQL SELECT statement, (MySQL is not something I'm too familiar with).

This query give me the correct results I am looking for in the correct order (by greater number of stats), but I need to get a particular value from the results.

```
SELECT id, stats,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM statistics.web_stats p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
ORDER BY stats DESC;
```

Gives me this expected result:

```
id,stats,rank
999,291,1
1137,82,2
1084,79,3
1111,60,4
1097,55,5
1094,51,6
1109,50,7
1112,49,8
1154,44,9
1082,36,10
```

What I need to do it get the rank value of any particular id, for example, in my PHP code, how would I find the rank position of id 1111 (to return the rank value of '4')?

I'm stuck with hoe to further extract values from the results. Do I need to save them somehow, or can I further expand the MySQL query?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033051/how-to-get-rank-position-from-currank   the solution is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any one of the solutions:

1. You need to use a subquery to maintain rank position.

This will give you a result whose rank is 4:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT id, stats,
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM statistics.web_stats p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
    ORDER BY stats DESC
) AS stat
WHERE rank = 4;
```

2. You can even use `LIMIT OFFSET` to query as they are already in order:

```
    SELECT id, stats,
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM statistics.web_stats p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
    ORDER BY stats DESC 
    LIMIT 4, 1
```

Comment: @SandrinJoy I didn't get you? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi, Thank you, option 1 worked except that I did not know the rank number, that is exact the value I needed, but I changed the WHERE clause to be the id=1111 and this solved by problem, thank you!